# Python (OpenPyxl) openpyxl not write anything

Tags: python, openpyxl

Code :

> ```
> wb = Workbook()
> sdwbb = load_workbook(sdpath)
>
> filename = os.path.basename(sdpath)
>
> bulan = "September"
>
> try:
>    sdp = sdwbb[bulan]
> except:
>     sdwbb.create_sheet(bulan)
>     wb.save(filename)
>     time.sleep(0.5)
>     sdp = sdwbb[bulan]
> cell_one = sdp['F1']
> cell_one.value = 'test'
> sdwbb.save(filename)
> ```

for your information I doesn't get any error but its doesn't write anything cell f1 sheet September

what I trying to do is to write on specific workbook ,sheet ,and cell

Comment: Why are you creating a workbook and also opening an existing one? You can just open the existing one. I am also unable to replicate your error

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to write "test" in cel F1 (in the current sheet) in the file test.xlxs in the same folder:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

ws["F1"] = "test"
        
wb.save("test.xlsx")
print("done")
```

It's as easy as that :).

Also, you should devenitly check out the documentation of openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook

Comment: wdym with current sheet? i want it to write on a specific sheet

Comment: just select the seed then: " ws = wb["sheet"] "